# Get the week start date and week end date from week number in raw query

Tags: sql, database, laravel

## !Get the week start date and week end date from week number in raw query #2 after group all ids in array

```
$test=DB::table('bookings')
->select([

     'bookings.organization_id',
     DB::raw('week(bookings.created_at) as week'), // this give me week number I need start date and end date starting date Sunday and end date Saturday 
     DB::raw('year(created_at) as year'),
```

the second after group by organization_id I need all booking id in array not string

```
// I try this but give like this "1,4,6,7,9"  I need ["1","4","6","7","9"]

DB::raw('group_concat(bookings.id) as bookings_id'),
```

Comment: Why can't you iterate the result set and populate your array?

Comment: two question #1 changes week number to start date and end date.  and I am new to db raw I need code to understand. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the start and end of week you can use this:

```
$test=DB::table('bookings')
->select([
'bookings.organization_id',
  DB::raw('DATE(bookings.created_at   + INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK(bookings.created_at)) DAY) as start_date'),
  DB::raw('DATE(bookings.created_at + INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK(bookings.created_at)) DAY) as end_date')
])
->get();
```

And for second question:

`MySQL` does not have concept of `array` type for data.

You need to explode the data into an array, using `php` code like this:

```
$bookingsIds = explode(',', $test->bookings_id);
```

Comment: what about "DB::raw('week(bookings.created_at) as week'), // this give me week number I need start date and end date starting date Sunday and end date Saturday"